# Calling Ajax periodically

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am calling a Java script function from my view page (MVC razor) which initiates an AJAX call. I want this to periodically re-occur. For some reason its going in a recursive loop

```
function GetData(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "GET",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: onSuccess,
        error: onError,
        complete: function(xhr, status) {
            setTimeout(GetData(url), 5000);
        }
    });
}

function onSuccess(data, status, xhr) {
    for (var key in data) {
        if (data.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var id = data[key].id;
            var value = data[key].value;
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = value;
        }
    }
}
```

On the html page side its a call to this function on page load

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    GetData("someurl");
</script>
```

Any idea why its going recursive when I am setting timeout in complete callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setTimeout(GetData(url), 5000);` calls `GetData` function immediately and indeed goes into infinite loop.

Instead you want to pass function as first argument:

```
setTimeout(function() {
  GetData(url);
}, 5000);
```